# If I delay a council mission, do I lose it?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

In XCOM: Enemy Within / Unknown if you choose to delay the Council mission to investigate the fishing village (full of chryssalids) as it's just too difficult for your current troops, does it ever come around again?

The last couple of games I've started I've gotten it extremely early so I don't want to keep risking soldiers getting killed when I have no Revive perks or decent weapons.

Comment: [This question's](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160851) answers seem to imply it won't come around again, but that missing it is also no big deal.

Comment: That link had a lot of good strategies to deal with the mission, as well.  If you have a save prior to doing loadout, troop choice can be quite important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not, and you will incur in a massive FEAR penalty, which in turn will bite you at the end of the month as it's very likely for you to lose a country or two due to that.

The only missions that do recurr are the main story missions and EXALT (The main Exalt missions that is)

Comment: So either way I'd suffer a spike in fear?  By that I mean by not taking it on, or by taking it and failing as my troops are not capable enough to do it?  At the moment it takes 3-4 soldiers per Chryssalids, so fighting a map full of them would be near impossible!   Is there a difference in fair rating for skipping / failing a mission?

Comment: Pretty much screwed yes. I'm not sure on whether you lose more by skiping or failing, however, you also have to account lost troops.

The only thing that can minimize damage on Chryssalid missions is to rescue a lot of civillains without losing a lot of troops, you'll fail but the penalty will be lower. But then again, that's only for Terror Missions, not for the fishing village.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just fly there and abort (or kill a few lids for xp and then abort) and take a very small penalty.  You can't keep the corpses anyway due to the bombing, so the success condition isn't so valuable unless Canada's in real trouble.  If nothing else, OP, if you're not in iron man just try the abort and let us know.

Comment: That's an option, but the penalty will still be there

Comment: Agreed, there will be *a* penalty, but I'm not sure it's "massive" if you abort (it's not a terror mission).

Comment: The reward for the mission is lowering panic because the mission appears in a region that you will most likely lose due to high panic anyway at the end of the month. While it may not give you THAT much of a penalty, you WILL lose the country unless you waste a satellite there